# How do I do a classification problem with autoencoders (AEs)

Tags: autoencoders

I understand that if I want to fine-tune for classification, I can discard the output layer and link the hidden layer to a classifier, do backpropagation to get an improved weight.

So when I want to do testing phase, I only need to feed the hidden layer of testing data to the classifier to get an actual result, right? I really need some confirmation here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, once you've trained the network as an autoencoder, if you're only interested in classification you can just ignore the decoding part of the network and just feed the output of the deepest hidden layer into the classifier layer.

[This](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Stacked_Autoencoders) page might be informative.

Comment: But then do you retrain the encoder layer with the softmax layer with the training data?

Comment: Yeah, you can train all layers together once they're combined. This is called "fine-tuning" if you want to read more about it.

Comment: @mobeets the link now goes to an empty page. Google has a cached version [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ufEWAIqyw3cJ:ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Stacked_Autoencoders+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)